# Adding our own alias for rootObject, Criteria Query, Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When ever the query is getting generated, Hibernate provides it's own naming conventions, which is getting messy for huge queries,

for Example: select * from user generated_alias0 .....[long query]

do we have any property or way to give our own alias so that it will be easy to track them on the console it self, not in a way like to copy it to another text editor then highlight with help of some tool

What I tried it:
To give an alias to root object itself like:

```
Root<User> userRoot = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
userRoot.alias("user");
```

but the query getting generated is still the same:

select * from user generated_alias0 .....

Answer (score 0):

Using createAlias  you can handle it . Ref: This [Hibernate: Criterion. Add Alias to Criterion Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528578/hibernate-criterion-add-alias-to-criterion-object) might be duplicate .